# SVM class not found error

Tags: php, svm, web-hosting

I tried to run this code in my website which is hosted by **000webhost**:

```
<?php
$data = array(
array(-1, 1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2),
array(1, 1 => 0.22, 5 => 0.01, 94 => 0.11),
  );

 $svm = new SVM();
 $model = $svm->train($data);

 $data = array(1 => 0.43, 3 => 0.12, 9284 => 0.2);
  $result = $model->predict($data);
var_dump($result);

?>
```

But I got an error saying:

> Fatal error: Class 'SVM' not found
>   /home/a8228945/public_html/svex.php on line 7

How can I solve this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to enable the extension php SVM : http://pecl.php.net/package/svm

> LibSVM is an efficient solver for SVM classification and regression
>   problems. The svm extension wraps this in a PHP interface for easy use
>   in PHP scripts.